# Styling My Modal , I need My modal to have a back groundcolor of red

Tags: php, html

I need the background to be red , and the text to be white , I have tried to do it in the scss file but it just doesn't link , I used bootstrap 5

```
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                    
                    <div class="modal-content">
                
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                
                                <div class='col-12 modal-title text-center'>
                                    <h5>Where to look for Lambdaboard</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-plain-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    
                                                </div>
                    
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                
                                                        <img src="<?=$base_url?>_images/animation.gif" alt="Animated Gif">
                                        
                                                             <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                 
                                                                <h5 class='col-12 modal-title text-center'>
                                                                    A Fraction of the places you can find it
                                                                    
                                                                </div>
                        
                                                            </div>
                    
                                                        </div>
                
                                                    </div>
            
                                                </div>
        
                                            </div>
    
                                    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a custom style class on your modal div and an other where your text is that dooesn't work ? It should